# How can I merge a guest post with a new account?

Tags: support

I asked a question over at AskUbuntu(as a guest), and I'd like to be able to edit and comment on this new account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Email us via the 'contact us' link at the bottom of any page and link to your post as well as the new account.

We might have to ask you to provide some additional details, but it's all best done over email.